# jQuery plugin photopile not working, but so simple, anything I might be doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-plugins, photo-gallery

**Plugin I'm trying to do**: http://photopile-js.com/ you can see it literally has like.... 3 lines of instructions that I've pasted below. but somehow instead of a pile of photos, I get the output attached in the image file. In other words, it looks like the CSS is working, but the JS is never called
[image]
**Fixes I tried but that didn't work**:
- Instead of using the suggested jQuery and jQuery UI links from photopile-js.com, I went to jQuery and tried to use the latest source URLs (this is the code that is NOT commented out. The code that IS commented out is the source URLs recommended on photopile-JS)
- I tried to add a script to the page so that on window load the function is called, and I got the function from the photopile.js file
- I tried to require `photopile.js` before `application.js` in the `javascript include tag` of the application layout file

**Photopile instructions code**

```
<body>
...
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="YOUR/PATH/TO/photopile.js"></script>
</body>

<div class="photopile-wrapper">
  <ul class="photopile">
   <li>
     <a href="PATH/TO/YOUR/FULLSIZE/IMAGE">
     <img src="PATH/TO/YOUR/THUMBNAIL/IMAGE" alt="Image description" ... />
     </a>
   </li>
   <!-- Add as many list items as you require for your gallery :) -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

**View code**:

```
<div class="photopile-wrapper">
  <ul class="photopile">
    <li><%= link_to "#{image_tag('Photo A.png')}".html_safe, "javascript:;" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "#{image_tag('Photo B.png')}".html_safe, "javascript:;" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "#{image_tag('Photo C.png')}".html_safe, "javascript:;" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "#{image_tag('Photo E.jpg')}".html_safe, "javascript:;" %></li>
    <!-- Add as many list items as you require for your gallery :) -->
  </ul>
</div>
<%= javascript_include_tag "photopile", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "photopile" %>

<script> <!-- I added this, didn't work -->
window.onload = function init() {
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain why this is the case... but I tried it a lot and it made the difference:

Instead of using a `javascript_include_tag` for the jquery files, I literally had to use the `script src`. And that literally did it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have all of the photos in a single < li > tag. I haven't used the library, but are they meant to be in separate list tags?

Something like this?

```
<li>
      <%= link_to "#{image_tag('Photo A.png')}".html_safe, "javascript:;" %>
</li>
<li>
      <%= link_to "#{image_tag('Photo B.png')}".html_safe, "javascript:;" %>
</li>
```

Comment: OH yes, that's also a good catch, but alas, didn't fix my problem (see revised question with improved code).

Answer (score 0):

Where are you loading your Javascript?

Try loading after the markup associated with your photopile, or at the very least load photopile.js afterward.